# Why isn't my function being called?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm just doing some simple JavaScript homework but I can't figure out why my function isn't being called.

All I'm having te function do is `alert("test")` at the moment because I have to make sure the function is called before I actually write what it does. The JS file `DOMassignment_3_ext.js` resides in the same folder as the HTML file.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>DOM Assignment: #3</title>
<script src="DOMassignment_3_ext.js">
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Christmas Mad Libs</h2>
<form name="words">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="name"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Body-part</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="body"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Animal</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="animal"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="button" onlick="madlibs(name, body, animal)" value="Submit">
</form>
<p>
<b class="name"></b> the Red-<b class="body"></b> <b class="animal"></b><br>
Had a very shiny <b class="body"></b><br>
And if you ever saw it<br>
You would even say it glows<br>
And all of the other <b class="animal"></b><br>
Used to laugh and call him names<br>
They never let poor <b class="name"></b><br>
Join in any <b class="animal"></b> games<br>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
function madlibs(name, body, animal){
  alert("test");
}
```

Comment: You have a typo: `<input type="button" onlick="madlibs(name, body, animal)" value="Submit">` should be `<input type="button" onclick="madlibs(name, body, animal)" value="Submit">`. Typo is in `onclick` attribute name

Comment: The `onclick` attribute is misspelled on your input.

Comment: `onlick`... go ahead and start licking your computer.

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="button" onlick="madlibs(name, body, animal)" value="Submit">
```

Should be:

```
<input type="button" onclick="madlibs(name, body, animal)" value="Submit">
```

Comment: I prefer the first version, I definitely think there should be such an event. Especially with the new touch screens that have taste simulations in them.

Comment: @ItayMoav-Malimovka I don't know.  Texting and driving is dangerous enough.  Imagine what would happen if they had to lick the phone!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are passing variables that don't exist! `name` does (there will always be a global variable `name`, but `body` and `animal` do not. Therefore, when you invoke the function as so:

```
onlick="madlibs(name, body, animal)"
onclick="madlibs(name, body, animal)" // and even when you spell it correctly
```

Javascript will say "`body`? I don't know anything called `body`!" It will then throw an error (a `ReferenceError` to be precise) and stop running the code. This means `madlibs` will not be called.

Until such a time as you have defined these variables, you can simply leave them out of the call:

```
onclick="madlibs()"
```

(In reality, it would be better to learn how to attach event handlers with Javascript, but that's a different story.)

---

Looking again, it's *possible* that these variables are defined in `DOMassignment_3_ext.js`, but it seems unlikely, given the name of the file...